# Fingerprint Reader

Tags: c#

Would like to write a small program that for my company.
I want to have her employees enter the building with a fingerprint reader. Can anyone of you tell me how  how do I connect with (x628-t) fingerprint device . reading time attendance  across tcp/ip connection

Comment: From your response to @sohnee its evident that this question is too vague - or perhaps the "answer" is "no" (as in no one of us can tell you). To address this we need to understand what it is that you can't do and to know more about the hardware. If you don't know where to start ask for an outline approach. If you have specific issues with elements of the application ask about each of those in turn and you *may* get more useful answers.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an article on finger print readers and .NET.

In this blog, the fingerprint reader is used from .NET - the example is in VB.NET, but you should be able to "transcribe" to C# really easily.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/coding4fun/archive/2007/03/06/1815291.aspx

Comment: i have not microsoft  fingerprint device .i have anohter

Answer (score -1):

If you have a finger print reader device, then the supplier of that device most likely also has an SDK for you to use and develop applications with. That SDK is usually accompanied by documentation and example projects. Those SDKs usually handle how to talk to the device and getting a scanned image of the finger print back.

What you choose to do with it after the scanning process is complete, like talk to your company subsystems via TCP/IP or any other transport mechanism, has nothing to do with the finger print reader.

Comment: i would like to how to get time attendance data from x628 fingerbrint device to loaded them in my c# application

Comment: @shmandor: As I said, your supplier should be able to get you the x628 SDK, if available, so that you can use its examples, etc., to develop what you need.